# Uncaught module cordova/confighelper not found in browser platform

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova App, but I have installed the plugin splash screen from the [official repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) using this command:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

I am developing under Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed the platform browser for developing my app faster (using Chrome).

I have added this to my config.xml (like you can see in the official [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#browser-quirks))

```
<platform name="browser">
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="images/browser/splashscreen.jpg" /> <!-- defaults to "img/logo.png" -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" /> <!-- defaults to "3000" -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="green" /> <!-- defaults to "#464646" -->
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" /> <!-- defaults to "true" -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenWidth" value="600" /> <!-- defaults to "170" -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenHeight" value="300" /> <!-- defaults to "200" -->
</platform>
```

But I have a JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught module cordova/confighelper not found
cordova.js:891 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:884 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

How can I solve it? Thanks!! If I remove the plugin, I don't see this error.

Comment: I've never had success getting cordova plugins to fire in the browser; especially device ready.

Comment: But... in the documentation seems to work... :(

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal complete, verifiable example of your code in this question (your app.js, config.xml, and a minimal index.html).

Comment: I just have added the plugin, not modification. Empty app with no more code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the splashscreen plugin, `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`, for the browser platform.

It [appears to have been resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8223).

To fix the issue, comment out the splashscreen references in `www/cordova_plugins.js` or uninstall the plugin.

Edit: I just realised you've done this...

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. 
I've resolve it by removing my browser 3.5.0 platform and reAdd version 4.0.0
After that it work again.